# Sparklyr - fail to connect to "local"

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, sparklyr

When trying to connect to spark using sparklyr, I get the following error message:

```
'Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort, sessionId,  : 
  Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond.'
```

There is no other info displayed in Console.  I'm running Spark 3.0.0 and Java 8 RE.

I went looking for the .log file and found it. This is what it contained:

```
'Cool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program.
```

My local account name contains 'Cool' with spaces in the name, so it may have to do with the file path I set in PATH for spark_home. How can I include spaces in the file path?  I've tried different combinations of quotation marks, but still get the same error message.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.2    sparklyr_1.4.0 shiny_1.5.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        later_1.1.0.1     compiler_4.0.2    pillar_1.4.6      dbplyr_1.4.4      r2d3_0.2.3       
 [7] base64enc_0.1-3   tools_4.0.2       odbc_1.2.3        digest_0.6.25     bit_4.0.4         jsonlite_1.7.1   
[13] evaluate_0.14     tibble_3.0.3      lifecycle_0.2.0   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.7       DBI_1.1.0        
[19] rstudioapi_0.11   parallel_4.0.2    yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.17         fastmap_1.0.1     withr_2.3.0      
[25] httr_1.4.2        knitr_1.30        askpass_1.1       rappdirs_0.3.1    generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.3.4      
[31] htmlwidgets_1.5.1 hms_0.5.3         bit64_4.0.5       rprojroot_1.3-2   tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2       
[37] forge_0.2.0       R6_2.4.1          rmarkdown_2.3     tidyr_1.1.2       purrr_0.3.4       blob_1.2.1       
[43] magrittr_1.5      promises_1.1.1    backports_1.1.10  htmltools_0.5.0   ellipsis_0.3.1    assertthat_0.2.1 
[49] xtable_1.8-4      mime_0.9          httpuv_1.5.4      config_0.3        tinytex_0.26      openssl_1.4.3
```